# How to run a function on each of array elements in Javascript

Tags: javascript, extjs, functional-programming, extjs4.1

I wish to run a function that exists on each of my array's elements.
I know it can be done with a for loop, an each, and map, but none of these pursue a pure functional approach.
for example, with map it would look something like this:

`var a = [1,2,3].map(function(item) { item.funcName(params); });`

I do not care about the return values of these functions

example code I wish I had:
`var a = [1,2,3].magicRun('funcName'[, paramsArray]);;`

Is there such a thing in pure JS?
It there such a thing in ExtJS? (which I have avail. loaded ver. 4.1)

Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried [`Array.forEach`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach)?

Comment: What are trying to achieve exactly ? `magicRun` should do what exactly ? What do you expect should happen with that `paramsArray` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's nothing exactly like what you want in pure JS, and I don't think ExtJS has it either (but I haven't used ExtJS in anger since version 3.something, so there might be)

[MooTools](http://mootools.net/) however adds this `invoke` method to `Array`:

```
invoke: function(methodName){
  var args = Array.slice(arguments, 1);
  return this.map(function(item){
    return item[methodName].apply(item, args);
  });
},
```

...which being released under the MIT license, you can lift without any bad karma

Comment: although not a solution to the problem, it is an answer to the question... I accept. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

In pure Js you can add the function "map" to Array object prototype

In this example I make the sqrt of every element of the array

```
if (!Array.prototype.map)
    Array.prototype.map = function(fun)
    {
        var len = this.length;
        if (typeof fun != "function")
            throw new TypeError();
        var res = new Array(len);
        for (var i = 0; i < len; ++i)
            res[i] = fun(this[i]);
        return res;
};


var numbers = [1, 4, 9];
var roots = numbers.map(Math.sqrt);

//could be an alert
console.log("roots is : " + roots );
```

Comment: this approach runs an external function on each of the array's items (Math.sqrt) not a function of the item itself

Comment: Thats what I understood it should do sorry :)

Answer (score 0):

```
if (!Array.prototype.forEach)
{
  Array.prototype.forEach = function(fun /*, thisp*/)
  {
    var len = this.length;
    if (typeof fun != "function")
      throw new TypeError();

    var thisp = arguments[1];
    for (var i = 0; i < len; i++)
    {
      if (i in this)
        fun.call(thisp, this[i], i, this);
    }
  };
}
```

exemple:

```
<html>
<head>
<title>JavaScript Array forEach Method</title>
</head>
<body>
<script type="text/javascript">
if (!Array.prototype.forEach)
{
  Array.prototype.forEach = function(fun /*, thisp*/)
  {
    var len = this.length;
    if (typeof fun != "function")
      throw new TypeError();

    var thisp = arguments[1];
    for (var i = 0; i < len; i++)
    {
      if (i in this)
        fun.call(thisp, this[i], i, this);
    }
  };
}

function printBr(element, index, array) {
  document.write("<br />[" + index + "] is " + element ); 
}

[12, 5, 8, 130, 44].forEach(printBr);

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

source: http://www.tutorialspoint.com/javascript/array_foreach.htm